# Why isn't my function returning the count? (Binary Tree)

Tags: c++

Everything in my program works perfectly, except it is not showing the count for the field. I tried to change some codes but it does not seem to display it in the output. It seems like a easy mistake or something obviously but I have no idea why it doesn't display it. Can someone help?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T>

class BinaryTree
{
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node* leftChild;
        Node* rightChild;

        Node(T dataNew)
        {
            data = dataNew;
            leftChild= NULL;
            rightChild = NULL;
        }
    };
private:
    Node* root;

    void Add(T new_Data, Node* &the_Root)
    {
        if (the_Root == NULL)
        {
            the_Root = new Node(new_Data);
            return;
        }

        if (new_Data < the_Root->data)
            Add(new_Data, the_Root->leftChild);
        else
            Add(new_Data, the_Root->rightChild);
    }
    int countTree(Node* the_Root)
    {
        if (the_Root == NULL)
            return 0;  
        else {
            int count = 1;  
            count += countTree(the_Root->leftChild);

            count += countTree(the_Root->rightChild);

            return count;  
        }
    } 
    void PrintTree(Node* the_Root)
    {
        if (the_Root != NULL)
        {
            cout << the_Root->data <<" ";
            PrintTree(the_Root->leftChild);
            PrintTree(the_Root->rightChild);
        }
    }

public:
    BinaryTree()
    {
        root = NULL;
    }

    void AddItem(T new_Data)
    {
        Add(new_Data, root);
    }

    int countTree()
    {
        return countTree(root);
    }

    void PrintTree()
    {
        PrintTree(root);
    }
};

int main()
{
    BinaryTree<int> *myBT = new BinaryTree<int>();
    myBT->AddItem(6);
    myBT->AddItem(5);
    myBT->AddItem(4);
    myBT->AddItem(18);
    myBT->AddItem(6);
    myBT->PrintTree();
    myBT->countTree();
}
```

Comment: "...not showing", "...doesn't display it"? But never even attempted to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The count won't be shown simply because you didn't write any code to show the count.

Try changing `myBT->countTree();` to `cout << myBT->countTree();`, and you will see the count printed.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually doing anything with the result of `myBT->countTree()`. Try printing it:

```
std::cout << myBT->countTree() << std::endl;
```